# Where can I ask for a specific flash animation (free\paypal payment)?

Tags: website-design, flash, graphics

Is there any site I can write a request for a specific flash animation that I desire?

What is the recommended user-friendly software to create flash that a newbie like me can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any site I can write a rewuest for a specific flash animation I desire?

Try [oDesk](https://www.odesk.com/?_redirected) or [freelancer.com](http://www.freelancer.com/)

> What is the recommended user-friendly software to create flash a newbie like me can ues?

Nothing beats the [Flash IDE](http://www.adobe.com/products/flash.html) if you're new. The [Flex framework](http://www.adobe.com/products/flex.html) is also an option, but requires a little more know-how.